# File upload module for ZF2

Tags: file-upload, module, zend-framework2

I would like to integrate a file upload feature to an application coded with `ZF2`. I have found some material on the internet ([link1](http://www.deanclatworthy.com/2012/07/unique-filenames-when-uploading-using-zend_filter_file_rename-zend-framework/), [link2](http://www.fgsoft.se/blog/26-upload-file-using-zend-framework)) but every time the file upload is handled via a form within the current controller.

In my application, there are many controllers from which users can upload files, and I also do quite a bit of processing on every uploaded file (*e.g. authorization, creation of thumbails, gathering of information such as file size, image dimension, number of pages in document...*) and I would therefore like to centralize the code related to the uploading of files in one place.

I was thinking I could render file upload forms from different controllers, but have the `form` `action` always pointing to the same `URL` (e.g. `/uploads`) and have my routing send those files to an `Uploads` module for instance. I have been unsuccessfully looking for `ZF2` file upload modules on `google` and the [`ZF2 modules site`](http://modules.zendframework.com/) so I'm thinking this may not be a very good idea, hence my question:

**What would be the limitations (*what useful features wouldn't I be able to use*) of generating the file upload form in one controller, and handling the uploading of files in a controller of a separate module?**

Comment: Create a controller plugin(helper) in your module. Process the file uploading in your class helper.

Answer (score -1):

To create a file upload form field you need to do something like this:

```
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

$file = new Element('file');
$name->setAttributes(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
    'label' => 'Upload file',
));

$form = new Form('myform');
$form->add($file);
```

On the view side:

```
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('one_of_the_routes'));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$form->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
?>

<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
<p>
    <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('file')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('file')); ?>
</p>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

Currently there is a problem on the validator side (at least when I checked last) but I am sure it will be fixed soon. Mean while I just aproach $_FILES from the model.

Note: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-327

And read the man at: http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.quick.start.html

Comment: Thanks Michael but my question was not about how creating a file upload form, but more regarding the integration of a file upload feature inside a module.